# view all javascript variables of a GWT app

Tags: javascript, gwt, variables

This question is mainly for security purposes. I need to know if it is possible to view by any means (plugins, programmatically or whatever) a list of all variables and their values in a gwt application compiled to javascript.

Let's say I have a variable x created by gwt in its normal deployment mode.... let's just ignore how did the value get there... Can the user somehow get to know that there is a var called x and its value...

Please note that I am not looking for software engineering best practices, the question is over simplified so that we get to the point. I know that I should not have anything sensitive on the client on the first place... but please let's just skip that since the case is a much bigger story...

Thanks a lot..

Comment: I have been able to list variables created outside gwt through DOM and progrmmatically... but I cannot find the gwt variables anywhere..

Comment: You kinda knew the awnser to this didn't you =P

Comment: Create a sensitive variable (ie. "fooSensitive"), compile to js, check js code to see if you can spot the value (not the variable name). If you can see it, harmful javascript code can reach it.

Comment: I know I am *supposed* to find it... but I can't!! as far as I can see, it is not in the dom...  I wonder where the gwt compiler hides them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short awnser... yes..

GWT compiles to javascript and obfuscates everything, that said, all information is available from the compiled source if one knows what to look for. If someone succeeds in injecting a simple script tag into your application, they can simple retreive all scripts through XMLHttpRequest and parse them as text. No matter how obfuscated, it's theoretically possible to get what you want from any javascript source. If you can see it in the raw script file, it's attainable, doesn't really matter if it's locked away in anonymous closures or whatnot, any JS security mechanism can be circumvented.

Main condition is to get control of the page (script injection).

To quote yourself: " I know that I should not have anything sensitive on the client on the first place..."

If it's worth hacking, people will try it.

Comment: Actually, I run over SSL.. and I already don't send the critical data... but some data are sent that it would be better if the user don't see... so I've set a complex crypto scheme to prevent anybody from reading XmlHttpReqs data... but normally it has a performance hit... so I was trying to assess if it is worth it... that is why I asked if it could be accessed.... it looks that it can be accessed but I'm happy to know that it is not trivial...

Comment: As I said the data is not critical, what I want is that the user cannot see values unless he spends days reverse engineering the app and debugging and so on... I am sure if he spent enough time... he will eventually break it since the data will be decrypted some time... but I am trying to make it really hard!

Comment: Putting you app behind a solid auth should (theoretically) keep the burglars out, so you only have to worry about your users. The important question then is; What kind of users (tech level) and is there a reason for the users to backwards engineer the values (cheating, disgruntled employee syndrom etc)? What is the impact when the values do become easily atainable?

Comment: well, mostly not catastrophic... most data is not critical... but he might get some info he should not normally know... 

The bottom line for me is that while everything is eventually crackable... gwt makes it hard... so, the crypto indeed does what It was supposed to do.. 

I think that I got the answer...

Answer (score 2):

GWT code is compiled to javascript. So ultimately user can use [javascript introspection](http://www.syger.it/Tutorials/JavaScriptIntrospector.html) to discover all objects and their properties.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No, not unless you know what you are looking for.

GWT compiler does something called as cross-compiling, it transforms java code into java script/ECMA script. The mapping between a variable in java to that in generated script is not straight forward. The language semantics are not the same; the compiler tries to optimize and generates obfuscated JS (to reduce the size). You can tweak this to certain extent by passing arguments at compile time (by setting PRETTY). This still does not guarantee a one on one mapping.

On different quote, even decompiled java code does not look like the original source. ( thats' the complexity of the problem)

Comment: I understand the complexity of trying to make any sort of reverse engineering with gwt cross-compiled obfuscated optimized javascript... but can the user list all gwt variables names? as I said I am able to do this with all js code in the page ... but not gwt.. the variables are hidden somewhere!!!

Comment: Did you check for unobstrusive javascript in resultant page? that is one way of accessing java-script from a different file.

Comment: I meant, did you check all java-script files referred in the html page. Unobtrusive scripting is a practice where the files are referred rather than included (akeen to link tag). The script tag would contain reference to it. Eg: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../dataprism/dataprism.nocache.js">

Comment: I am not sure how this relates to the question.. I am not looking for malicious code... I am writing an app and am trying to make some security related decisions based on whether the user can view the variable values...

Comment: All the scripted variables/code are visible to the user provided the script executes on client-side. A tool like IE developer toolbar or Firebug can easily show that. The source files are mostly declared in the script tag as described above. On a different note, what sort of security decisions would you take based on variable values? (out of curiosity).

Comment: I have been playing with firebug ... all what all scripts does is visible crystal clear.... except gwt... I cannot find its variables anywhere..
About what I am trying to do, I said that on another comment :)

Comment: On the top of my head there is only one way to introduce such a behavior, by using 'eval' and passing script as a string. It is difficult to answer without a common reference. Did you see the contents of blahblah...*.cache.html file? In addition to blah...*nocache.js this also contains a significant amount of js. Without a common reference it is difficult to discuss these. Copying the cache.html and reformatting it using netbeans js editor left me with 7265 lines. (I use ext-gwt). I do see with significant references to java class names from GWT API.